# How can I make Ubuntu Firefox render webpages similar to Windows/Mac Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts, screen, ubuntu-10.04

I just installed Ubuntu as my core operating system and am having a bit of a panic.. **Is there any strategy for making the fonts/browser defaults for browsers (and the OS in general) render similarly to Windows Vista or Mac OSX?** I'm afraid accurate web design work in this environment will be total guess work..

Comment: Did your definition of "accurate web design work" not include Linux in the first place?

Comment: I suppose I have set a standard for my visuals as the visuals on Windows and Mac Firefox browsers. Just trying to see if there's any way to make my os behave more like those operating systems as far as visuals go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox renders indeed [fonts differently in Linux/Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218851/ubuntu-firefox-renders-differently), because Microsoft TrueType fonts are missing, and because default font settings are different. Try to install Microsoft TrueType fonts (Arial, Trebuchet MS) with

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Then adjust the font settings in Firefox, i.e. open up Firefox, select

```
Edit >> Preferences >> Content >> Fonts & Colors - Advanced
```

The following [ubuntu font settings are described here](http://mozilla.doslash.org/ubuntu/fonts.html) and work for me:

```
Fonts for: Western
Proportional: Serif, Size 16
Serif: Times New Roman
Sans-serif: Arial
Monospace: Courier New, Size 12
```

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion is using tools like this one http://browsershots.org/ ; they are very slow, but can be handy sometimes.

Comment: what about for offline/localhost testing?

Comment: for offline testing you could install the windows/osx fonts and change the defaults, but i doubt they would render exactly as they should. another solution is using virtualization software and installing the needed os