# Text display in html (firefox) shows different in ubuntu and windows 7, why?

Tags: html, css, ubuntu

The `html+css` for Firefox in windows, looks fine, but same looks out of place in Firefox in Ubuntu. Please do let me know, as to how it can corrected, what should i do?

More info 1: The css code for the text in the attached image:

```
style="font-family:'Museo 300'; 
font-size:11px; 
text-align:left; 
color:#636466; 
padding-top:3px;"
```

Although am changing `Museo 300` to font to `Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif`, so it can load in any browser with these default fonts, but still i see the this problem.

*image attached*

[image: Windows 7 - firefox]
[image: Ubuntu - firefox]

Comment: please add the html and css.

Comment: Did you set preferred `font-family` in CSS ?

Comment: Now you can add image..

Comment: read this answer here this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/1218851/1868660

Comment: This answer here will help you understand problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/1218874/1868660 other then this you can use browser specific css http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/

Comment: Please include the *relevant* portions of your HTML and CSS in your question.

Comment: Put css style in first row of your css file. add font-family for body, like this body {font-family:"your font name goes here"

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the font you are using is not installed on the Ubuntu machine. To get around this you must supply the font yourself. [Google Fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) is a great way to do just this.

You can search their site for a suitable font, and then link it in your site `<head>`.

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And then use it in your CSS

```
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
```

Sadly, Google Fonts does not have the Museo font you are trying to use. However, you can use the `@font-face` CSS At-Rule to link to a font file which you are hosting on your site. Make sure that you only host the languages and font weight/style that you plan to use, and that your font file is limited to those same parameters. This will allow the file to be loaded much faster.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'My Custom Font';
    src: url('http://yoursite.com/yourfontfile.ttf') format('truetype');
}
p.customfont { 
    font-family: 'My Custom Font', Verdana, Tahoma;
}
```

([See this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107951))